# Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM - [SPARK]

Tags: java, apache-spark, twitter, stream, jvm

I'm trying to run the following code to get twitter information live:

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import twitter4j.auth.Authorization
import twitter4j.Status
import twitter4j.auth.AuthorizationFactory
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext

import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.HashingTF
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaReceiverInputDStream

val consumerKey = "xxx"
val consumerSecret = "xxx"
val accessToken = "xxx"
val accessTokenSecret = "xxx"
val url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json"

val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Twitter Streaming")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

val documents: RDD[Seq[String]] = sc.textFile("").map(_.split(" ").toSeq)


// Twitter Streaming
val ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc,Seconds(2))

val conf = new ConfigurationBuilder()
conf.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken)
conf.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessTokenSecret)
conf.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey)
conf.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret)
conf.setStreamBaseURL(url)
conf.setSiteStreamBaseURL(url)

val filter = Array("Twitter", "Hadoop", "Big Data")

val auth = AuthorizationFactory.getInstance(conf.build())
val tweets : JavaReceiverInputDStream[twitter4j.Status] = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, auth, filter)

val statuses = tweets.dstream.map(status => status.getText)
statuses.print()
ssc.start()
```

But when it arrives at this command: `val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)`, the following error appears:

> 17/05/09 09:08:35 WARN SparkContext: Multiple running SparkContexts
>   detected in the same JVM! org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one
>   SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). To ignore
>   this error, set spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true.

I have tried to add the following parameters to the sparkConf value, but the error still appears:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Twitter Streaming").setMaster("local[4]").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
```

If I ignore the error and continue running commands I get this other error:

> 17/05/09 09:15:44 WARN ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Restarting receiver
>   with delay 2000 ms: Error receiving tweets 401:Authentication
>   credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or
>   incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access
>   token/secret, and the system clock is in sync. \n\n\nError 401 Unauthorized  
>   HTTP ERROR: 401
>
> Problem accessing
>   '/1.1/statuses/filter.json'. Reason:Unauthorized

Any kind of contribution is appreciated. A greeting and have a good day.

Comment: Why are you using a JavaStreamingContext in a Scala program?

Comment: Also, how are you deploying your code? Is this inside a Spark-shell?

Comment: @RickMoritz yes, inside a spark-shell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**A Spark-shell already prepares a spark-session or spark-context** for you to use - so you don't have to / can't initialize a new one. Usually you will have a line telling you under what variable it is available to you a the end of the spark-shell launch process.
allowMultipleContexts exists only for testing some functionalities of Spark, and shouldn't be used in most cases.

Comment: So the solution would be to omit the following commands: `val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Twitter Streaming")` & `val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)`?. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yes - depending on your Spark version you may also have to substitute sc with spark.sparkContext (if Spark >=2.0)